# Android diary app - Search SQLite database and display results in ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a diary application in Android, and I want to be able to search a SQLite database for entries based on what a user types into an EditText field. The problem is that I have to use an older version, which makes using the RecyclerView difficult (I think). My setup is the following:

A SQLite database

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SecondDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static SecondDataBaseHelper secondDataBaseHelper;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    public final static String DATABASE_NM ="RECORD_OF_USER";
    public final static String TABLE_NM ="DATA_OF_USER";
    public final static String COL_1 = "ID";
    public final static String COL_2 = "SUBJECT";
    public final static String COL_3 = "ENTRY";
    public final static String COL_4 = "DATE";
    public final static String COL_5 = "LATITUDE";
    public final static String COL_6 = "LONGITUDE";


    public SecondDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NM, null, 1);
    }

    public static SecondDataBaseHelper databaseInstance(Context context) {
        if (secondDataBaseHelper == null) {
            secondDataBaseHelper = new SecondDataBaseHelper(context);
        }

        return secondDataBaseHelper;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NM +" (ID TEXT, SUBJECT TEXT, ENTRY TEXT, DATE TEXT, LATITUDE TEXT, LONGITUDE TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void addEntryToDatabase(Diary entry) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COL_1, entry.getId());
        contentValues.put(COL_2, entry.getSubject());
        contentValues.put(COL_3, entry.getContent());
        contentValues.put(COL_4, entry.getDate());
        contentValues.put(COL_5, entry.getLatitude());
        contentValues.put(COL_6, entry.getLongitude());

        db.insert(TABLE_NM, null, contentValues);
    }

    public void populateDiaryListArray() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

        try (Cursor result = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NM, null)) {
            if (result.getCount() != 0) {
                while (result.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = result.getString(1);
                    String subject = result.getString(2);
                    String content = result.getString(3);
                    String date = result.getString(4);
                    String latitude = result.getString(5);
                    String longitude = result.getString(6);

                    Diary diary = new Diary(id, subject, content, date, latitude, longitude);
                    Diary.diaryArrayList.add(diary);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void updateDiaryInDB(Diary entry) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COL_1, entry.getId());
        contentValues.put(COL_2, entry.getSubject());
        contentValues.put(COL_3, entry.getContent());
        contentValues.put(COL_4, entry.getDate());
        contentValues.put(COL_5, entry.getLatitude());
        contentValues.put(COL_6, entry.getLongitude());

        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NM, contentValues, COL_1 + " ?= ", new String[]{String.valueOf(entry.getId())});
    }

    public void deleteEntry(String id) {
        db.delete(TABLE_NM, COL_1 + "=" + id, null);
    }

}
```

./DiaryAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

public class DiaryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Diary>{
    public DiaryAdapter(Context context, List<Diary> entries) {
        super(context, 0, entries);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Diary diary = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_cell, parent, false);
        }

        TextView entryID = convertView.findViewById(R.id.entryID);
        TextView entrySubject = convertView.findViewById(R.id.entrySubject);

        entryID.setText(diary.getId());
        entrySubject.setText(diary.getSubject());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The Diary class itself

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Diary {
    private String id;
    private String subject;
    private String content;
    private String date;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    public static ArrayList<Diary> diaryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static String DIARY_EDIT_EXTRA = "diaryEdit";

    public Diary(String id, String subject, String content, String date, String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
        this.date = date;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public static Diary getDiaryForID(int passedDiaryID) {
        for (Diary diary : diaryArrayList) {
            if (Integer.parseInt((diary.getId())) == passedDiaryID) {
                return diary;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}
```

And the main app page itself, ./SearchEntries

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SearchEntries extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_entries);


    }
}
```

My XML page is set up as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SearchEntries">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?actionBarTheme"
        android:background="@color/darkGray">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchTextField"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:hint="Enter text here"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/diarySearchResults"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:divider="@color/darkGray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Basically, I want to enter text into the searchTextField in the XML file, and have it display in the ./diarySearchResults ListView field, where each entry is just comprised of the ID/Subject combo from the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data list from searched keywords in SQLite, then here is the simple query.

I've already made a method with your model class & DatabaseHelper to make it easy.
Just pass the desired keywords in it & get the job done.

```
private void searchDiaryData(String diaryId, String diarySubject){

    List<Diary> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NM +
            " WHERE " + SecondDataBaseHelper.COL_1 + " LIKE '" + diaryId + "%' OR "
            + SecondDataBaseHelper.COL_2 + " LIKE '" + diarySubject + "%'", null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SecondDataBaseHelper.COL_1));
                String _subject = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SecondDataBaseHelper.COL_2));
                String _content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SecondDataBaseHelper.COL_3));
                String _date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SecondDataBaseHelper.COL_4));
                String _latitude = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SecondDataBaseHelper.COL_5));
                String _longitude = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SecondDataBaseHelper.COL_6));

                Diary diaryModel = new Diary(
                        _id,
                        _subject,
                        _content,
                        _date,
                        _latitude,
                        _longitude
                );

                searchResults.add(diaryModel);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        diaryAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this, searchResults);
        diarySearchResults.setAdapter(diaryAdapter);
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's great! I think I only want to search by subject, so in my XML file, for my EditText field searchTextField, if I put in a term like "bananas" into that field, I can pass that string into searchDiaryData, and that will dump into the ListView?

Comment: Yes. Exaclty! You can changes the method arguments according to your need. 
If you want to pass other fields then create one more argument in method & pass that one in query using `OR " + SecondDataBaseHelper.COL_6 + " LIKE '" + keyword + "%'` and it will check the new keyword also.
If you want to get the result from two columns having same keyword then simply replace OR with AND, It will give you the data only when that columns contains same letters as the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-sqlite-listview-with-examples

Or

https://simplylearnprogramming.com/android/insert-data-in-to-sqlite-and-display-on-android-listview.html

This is old project to use listview. And you said you need to run it on old device.